# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, iis-7

I've never used php before and am trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008 instance on a Windows machine running IIS7 and PHP5.3.

I have downloaded and installed `SQLSRV30.EXE` from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20098) in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext` added this to `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini`:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
```

Then restarted the entire server. I still get fatal errors in my log file saying:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mssql_connect()
```

What do I need to do to connect to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 from PHP 5.3 running on IIS7/Windows Server 2008? I'm sure it's something really dumb that I'm missing...

**FULL PHPINFO -->** http://demo.mandibleweb.com/zapified/hello.php

phpinfo():

```
PHP Version 5.3.10





System 

Windows NT MWD001 6.1 build 7601 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack 1) i586 



Build Date 

Feb 2 2012 20:10:58 



Compiler 

MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008) 



Architecture 

x86 



Configure Command 

cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-zts" "--disable-isapi" "--disable-nsapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--with-enchant=shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze" 



Server API 

CGI/FastCGI 



Virtual Directory Support 

disabled 



Configuration File (php.ini) Path 

C:\Windows 



Loaded Configuration File 

C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini
```

Comment: I had similar situation (no MySQL block), and my solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179535/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect-in-c-apache-htdocs-test

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have just tried to install that extension on my dev server.

First, make sure that the extension is correctly enabled. Your `phpinfo()` output doesn't seem complete.

If it is indeed installed properly, your `phpinfo()` should have a section that looks like this:
[image]

If you do not get that section in your `phpinfo()`. Make sure that you are using the right version. There are both non-thread-safe and thread-safe versions of the extension.

Finally, check your `extension_dir` setting. By default it's this: `extension_dir = "ext"`, for most of the time it works fine, but if it doesn't try: `extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"`.

===========================================================================

**EDIT given new info:**

You are using the wrong function. `mssql_connect()` is part of the [Mssql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) extension. You are using microsoft's extension, so use `sqlsrv_connect()`, for the API for the microsoft driver, look at `SQLSRV_Help.chm` which should be extracted to your `ext` directory when you extracted the extension.

Comment: Sorry, here's the full [phpinfo()](http://demo.mandibleweb.com/zapified/hello.php), I do have the `sqlsrv` section

Comment: Yes, I was about to say I didn't see a mssql section in the phpinfo.

Comment: yay.. I'm in :), I had to download SQL Server 2012 Native Client http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29065

Comment: Thank you!  I had been using mssql_connect() till this post turned on the bulb.  I opened the chm and am using sqlsrv_connect() with no problems.  Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>php.ini</kbd> probably needs to read:
`extension=ext\php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll`

Or move the file to same directory as the php executable. This is what I did to my php5 install this week to get odbc_pdo working. :P

Additionally, that doesn't look like proper phpinfo() output. If you make a file with contents
`<? phpinfo(); ?>` and visit that page, the HTML output should show several sections, including one with loaded modules. (Edited to add: like shown in the screenshot of the above accepted answer)

Comment: Sorry, here's the full [phpinfo()](http://demo.mandibleweb.com/zapified/hello.php)

Answer (score 0):

I am using IIS and mysql (directly downloaded, without wamp or xampp)
My php was installed in c:\php
I was getting the error of "call to undefined function mysql_connect()"
For me the change of extension_dir worked.
This is what I did.
In the php.ini, Originally, I had this line

; On windows:
 extension_dir = "ext"

I changed it to:

; On windows:
 extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"

And it worked. Of course, I did the other things also like uncommenting the dll extensions etc, as explained in others remarks.