# "Call to undefined .. mssql_connect" when using PHP in IIS?

Tags: php, sql

May is ask you about how to connect to Microsoft SQL server 2005 enterprise using PHP.

I am using Appserv 2.5.10 ( Apache 2.2.8, PHP 5.2.6) and SQL server 2005

After  I place the extension download from this link :

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
```

enable the php.ini file by adding these lines.

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_52_ts_vc6.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_52_ts_vc6.dll
```

Restart Apache using this code to connect

```
$link = mssql_connect($server, $user, $pass);
```

Error shown in browser is

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in G:\AppServ\www\testmssql_connect.php on line 12

can anyone help me ?

NOTE: i am using windows server 2003 and i don't found this OS in OS supporting list of Microsoft Driver 3.0 for PHP. Is this issue cause the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this link:

- [PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986804/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect)

1) Check your PHP.INI file's `extension_dir`

2) Make sure you copied your .dlls into that directory (for example, into `C:\PHP\ext"`).

3) Create a dummy page to call `phpinfo();`.  Display the page in a browser.  Make sure you see entries for "sqlsrv".

'Hope that helps!

Comment: why i type sqlsrv_connect () this function has the black text color instead of blue color (because of function) so should i use sqlsrv_connect or mssql_connect

Comment: The new 3.0 API uses sqlsrv_connect(). I really find it shocking that people put such faith in their IDE, vs. understanding what the actual code is doing and how it works.  There is *not* necessarily any "tight binding" between the IDE and the underlying implementation.  The current MSSQL 3.0 driver documentation is here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2011/09/24/microsoft-drivers-3-0-for-php-for-sql-server-released.aspx.  Please *do* follow the steps above to make sure everything's configured correctly.  'Hope that helps...