# PHP: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

Tags: php

I'm trying to set up a registration page for my gaming service, seems like i'm stucked here :\

Here is the code:

```
<table class='ipb_table' cellspacing="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class='row2'>

<?php 

// fill in your mssql info here 

$mssql = array( 
        'host' => "zzzzzzzzzz", 
        'user' => "yyyyyyyyyy", 
        'pass' => "xxxxxxxxxx" 
    ); 

function anti_injection($sql) { 
   $sql = preg_replace(sql_regcase("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|&#092;*|--|&#092;&#092;&#092;&#092;)/"),"",$sql); 
   $sql = trim($sql); 
   $sql = strip_tags($sql); 
   $sql = addslashes($sql); 
   return $sql; 
} 


echo "<center>"; 

if($_POST['activ'] == '1') { 

        $accname = anti_injection($_POST['accname']); 
        $accmail = anti_injection($_POST['accmail']); 

        $accpass1 = anti_injection($_POST['accpass1']); 
        $accpass2 = anti_injection($_POST['accpass2']); 

        $con = mssql_connect($mssql['host'],$mssql['user'],$mssql['pass']);

        $result1 = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM account.dbo.USER_PROFILE WHERE user_id = '".$accname."'",$con); 
        $result2 = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM account.dbo.Tbl_user WHERE user_id = '".$accname."'",$con); 
        $result3 = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM account.dbo.Tbl_user WHERE user_mail = '".$accmail."'",$con); 

        $row1 = mssql_num_rows($result1); 
        $row2 = mssql_num_rows($result2); 
        $row3 = mssql_num_rows($result3); 

        $dk_time=strftime("%y%m%d%H%M%S"); 
         list($usec1, $sec1) = explode(" ",microtime()); 
         $dk_user_no=$dk_time.substr($usec1,2,2); 


        if(empty($accname) || empty($accpass1) || empty($accpass2)|| empty($accname) || empty($accmail)) { 
            echo "<br>You didnt fill in all fields<a href='javascript:history.back()'>Go Back</a>"; 
        } elseif($row1 > '0' || $row2 > '0') { 
            echo "<br>This Account name already exists.<a href='javascript:history.back()'>Go Back</a>"; 
        } elseif($row3 > '0') { 
            echo "<br>This E-Mail is already in use.<a href='javascript:history.back()'>Go Back</a>"; 
        } elseif($accpass1 != $accpass2) { 
            echo "<br>The passwords did not match<a href='javascript:history.back()'>Go Back</a>"; 
        } elseif($accpass1 == $accname) { 
            echo "<br>Account name and password are the same.<a href='javascript:history.back()'>Go Back</a>"; 
        } elseif(!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z]{3,15}$/i", $accname)) { 
            echo "<br>Enter a account name only with 0-9 , a-z and A-Z.<a href='javascript:history.back()'>Go Back</a>"; 
        } elseif(!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z]{3,15}$/i", $accpass1)) { 
            echo "<br>Enter a password only with 0-9 , a-z and A-Z.<a href='javascript:history.back()'>Go Back</a>"; 
        } elseif(!preg_match("/^&#092;w+([-+.]&#092;w+)*@&#092;w+([-.]&#092;w+)*&#092;.&#092;w+([-.]&#092;w+)*$/i",$accmail)) { 
            echo "<br>Your e-Mail is not correct.<a href='javascript:history.back()'>Go Back</a>"; 
        } elseif(strlen($accname) < 3 || strlen($accname) > 15) { 
            echo "<br>The Accountname must at least 3 indications long and may maximally 15 indications long.<a href='javascript:history.back()'>Go Back</a>"; 
        } elseif(strlen($accpass1) < 3 || strlen($accpass1) > 15) { 
            echo "<br>The Password must at least 3 indications long and may maximally 15 indications long.<a href='javascript:history.back()'>Go Back</a>"; 
        } else { 

            $accpass = md5($accpass1); 

            mssql_query("INSERT INTO account.dbo.USER_PROFILE (user_no,user_id,user_pwd,resident_no,user_type,login_flag,login_tag,ipt_time,login_time,logout_time,user_ip_addr,server_id) VALUES ('$dk_user_no','".$accname."','".$accpass."','801011000000','1','0','Y','".$date."',null,null,null,'000')",$con);
            mssql_query("INSERT INTO account.dbo.Tbl_user (user_no,user_id,user_pwd,user_mail,user_answer,user_question) VALUES ('$dk_user_no','".$accname."','".$accpass1."','".$accmail."','0','0')",$con);

            echo "<center><b><u>The account was successfully created. Have fun !</b></u></center><br><br>"; 
            echo "<center>Here is your login info again:</center>"; 
            echo "<center>Your account name is: <b>".$accname."</b></center>"; 
            echo "<center>Your password is: <b>".$accpass1."</b></center>"; 
            echo "DO NOT LOOSE THIS INFO, YOU MAY WRITE IS DOWN AND HIDE IT"; 
        } 

} else { 

    $con = mssql_connect($mssql['host'],$mssql['user'],$mssql['pass']); 
    $result1 = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM account.dbo.USER_PROFILE",$con); 
    $row1 = mssql_num_rows($result1); 

    echo "<center><b><u>This time we have ".$row1." Registed Accounts on our Server<br>Join us.</b></u></center><br>"; 
    echo "<form action='".$_SEVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='POST'>"; 
    echo "<center><table>"; 
    echo "<tr><td colspan='2' align='center'><b><u>Your Account Info</u></b></td></tr>"; 
    echo "<tr><td>Account Name</td><td><input type='text' name='accname' maxlength='12'></td></tr>"; 
    echo "<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type='password' name='accpass1' maxlength='12'></td></tr>"; 
    echo "<tr><td>Again pass.</td><td><input type='password' name='accpass2' maxlength='12'></td></tr>"; 
    echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"; 
    echo "<tr><td colspan='2' align='center'><b><u>Other account info</u></b></td></tr>"; 
    echo "<tr><td>Email</td><td><input type='text' name='accmail' maxlength='50'></td></tr>"; 
    echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"; 
    echo "<tr><td colspan='2' align='center'> 
        <input type='hidden' name='activ' value='1'> 
        <input type='submit' value='Create Account'></td></tr>"; 
    echo "</table></center>"; 
    echo "</form>"; 

} 

echo "</center>"; 

?>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This error is killing me, i really dont know whats wrong. If someone could help me by telling me how to fix this problem, i would be really happy! :D Also if someone have the time to clean as much as possible my script would be amazing :D

Please try to be really detailed so i can learn something new ^^

Comment: that's **not** a safe way to sanitise the data

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517220/call-to-undefined-mssql-connect-when-using-php-in-iis and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986804/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect

Comment: Sounds like mssql isn't installed

Comment: mssql is installed and is working

Comment: Dagon, if you know a better way to protect against sql injection, pls tell me :)

Comment: @DaemonSQL one word "PDO" ok so it's not one word :-)

Comment: @Dagon pls be more detailed :( how and where should i use that "PDO"

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php OR http://ellislab.com/codeigniter

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting downvotes for asking "someone to cleanup your code".

Answer (score 2):

According to php ms sql page:

This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.

On Windows, you should use SqlSrv, an alternative driver for MS SQL is available from Microsoft: » http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx .

Are you using php 5.3 ?

Comment: The PDO driver can be used to connect to mssql as well I believe.