# How to access remote SQL Server from PHP script

Tags: php, sql, database, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986804/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect)

I am developing a light-weight PHP application which accesses a remote SQL server db.

So far, I am out of luck in getting connection setup to SQL Server db through my PHP script.

I keep getting this error when I am trying to connect to sql DB:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()
```

I get similar error when I try `sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)` too

**Here is what I have already tried:**

I search for solution on web for hours, but nothing works.

I downloaded drivers from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
and unzipped them into php/ext folder

modified php.ini to add newly downloaded drivers lines:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll

[sqlsrv]
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems = 1
sqlsrv.LogSeverity = 1
sqlsrv.WarningReturnAsErrors = 0
```

Restarted the Apache server

But, **see phpinfo() output it doesn't have sqlserv in it** http://bit.ly/TkMC6V

Just so you know, I am developing this on my windows machine by installing EasyPHP. This website will be deployed on a Unix box. I tried to connect sql server through php on both Windows and Unix machine without any success.

Version info:

```
SQL Server 9.0.5000    
PHP ver 5.4.6    
Apache 2.4
```

I just dont get sqlsrv in my phpinfo() as mentioned in this question [PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986804/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect)

Is there a different way to install the drivers, other than what I have outlined above?

Let me know if you need more info.
Thanks!

Comment: See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986804/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect

Comment: +1 for link. But, I just don't get sqlsrv in my php info to start with. That is the main issue with me.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the dll or didnt configure it properly ?

Comment: Also check what is your extension directory. If it is in ext directory, then you might write ext/php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll

Comment: I double-checked, the dll are there in ext folder and php.ini has correct path for extension_dir. ( I just set absolute path). Wondering if there is an issue with version of dlls or something weird going on

Comment: Yes that was going to be my next comment. This extensions rely a lot on the version of PHP. You might try a lower version.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get same error when I try this extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll.

and phpinfo() is still the same http://bit.ly/TkMC6V

Comment: Wondering if someone can post version combination for php and the dll which they have working. Then I can downgrade to that exact version. I wish it throws some error "extension not loaded" etc. But, I just don't know what is happening and how to debug this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, by looking at [phpInfo()](http://bit.ly/TkMC6V) output carefully

```
Loaded Configuration File   C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\apache\php.ini
```

I was modifying php.ini in php directory. 
But, I needed to modify the one in apache directory

I can delete this silly question. 
But, I think it might be helpful for someone facing similar issue.

Jeez , I spent 4 hour on this stupid issue. :)