# PHP driver for MSSQL not working

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp, sqlsrv

I have a problem with the drivers that I've installed so my MSSQL could run side by side with PHP...

I have the following drivers placed in the directory file of PHP and also edited the .ini file of it:

- php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll

I have the following error message:

- `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`
- `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

And I have the following information about my PHP and MSSQL:

FOR PHP:

- PHP Version 5.4.12
- PHP installed via WAMP SERVER
- Architecture x64
- Thread safety enebled

FOR MSSQL:

- MSSQL 2014 Express Edition
- Am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to manage Databases

Those are all the following information... Am I at messed here? please help me, Im still a newbie here in PHP especially in MSSQL.. CHEERS!

---

This is my code @JayBhatt what must be corrected to run the following code:

```
<?php
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "sa";
$myPass = "joseph04";
$myDB = "cars";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT brand, model, year ";
$query .= "FROM cars ";
$query .= "WHERE brand='Honda'";

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query);

$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result);
echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" . ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>";

//display the results
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<li>" . $row["brand"] . $row["model"] . $row["year"] . "</li>";
}
//close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: On a different note, it's not wise to connect to the database by the SA user account as it has complete control over every database schema and mssql server settings. Best practice would be to have a sub user with sufficient privileges to a single or few schemas depending on the scale

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after a lot of research I had discovered that, Microsoft haven't released  a 64 bit  Version of driver for MSSQL.

The driver you have is for a 32 bit environment. And that's why it fails to load.  Try switching to a 32 bit environment of WAMP server and it will work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OOh I see, is it possible if I'd reinstall just the PHP component of the WAMP server? and how will I do that? thankyou!

Comment: Nope. You need the 32 bit Apache server as well. The best thing to do will be to install the whole 32 bit wamp.

Comment: Thank you Jay Bhatt! will try to install the 32 bit version of WAMP! :)

Comment: I still have a problem, okay I have downloaded and installed the 32 bit version of wampserver and it has php 5.5 with it, I've also place the required dll files but there is still a `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()` error when I run a simple test program. So I found this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UoXk8qJ82Y and followed the steps but still the same error, then I also place the following dll in the ext directory of php:

`php_ming.dll
php_mssql.dll`

and still the same error... I'm confused, I dont know what to do now :(

please help @JayBhatt

Comment: @JosephRojas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986804/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect

Comment: @JosephRojas and try using sqlsrv_connect()

Answer (score 0):

You can get unofficial x64 SQLSRV drivers for PHP . Try to install them. Here is your link. Just replace the dlls with the x64 dlls.

http://robsphp.blogspot.in/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html

Moreover  you should be  SQLSRV    functions to connect to the database.
and MSSQL functions. Both of them use different drivers.
You should use  "sqlsrv_connect" instead of "mssql_connect".

Refer: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php