# PHP Connecting to MSSQL Fatal Error

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Here is my problem: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect().`

I installed 2 drivers for this, as explained in other posts.

- php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
- php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll

  ```
  <?php
  $myServer = ".";
  $myUser = "LoginDisciples";
  $myPass = "********";
  $myDB = "Disciples";

  $dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
      or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 
  ?>
  ```

The login information is all correct.

Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql\_connect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986804/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect)

Comment: Then use PDO to connect to your database !!!

Answer (score -1):

You should use PDO
If there is a missing driver - here is an Ubuntu example how to install:

1) download driver `sudo apt-get install php5-xxx`
2) activate driver `sudo php5enmod xxx`
3) restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`