# PHP: Using MS SQL Driver php_mssql.dll in PHP 5.5?

Tags: php, sql-server, dll, database-connection

Please really need your help.
I'm using existing PHP 5.5 hosting other applications.
There is a new application that I need to migrate to my server.
The problem is that this application is using the old SQL Server driver php_mssql.dll.
I'm getting error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mssql_connect()
```

How can I still use the old driver php_mssql.dll in PHP5.5? Where can I download this dll?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql\_connect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986804/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect)

Comment: I also saw that post Abdulla, but its not the answer I'm looking for. because the answer there is suggesting the use of new MS SQL PHP driver sqlsrv_connect(), while I need to continue to use the old mssql_connect() . Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to use `mssql_connect()` instead of replacing it with `sqlsrv_connect()`? The problem is solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986804/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect

Comment: Hi ProtectedVoid, thanks for the reply. Because the application is already existing that uses mssql_connect() and it have many codes that will be hard to convert them right now as there is a deadline. But I agree that later I should use the new sqlsrv_connect(), but not at this time.

Comment: Then you should implement the project in a server that is compatible with your code's PHP version. Now it's `mssql_connect()` but later It could be other instruction not supported in the newer version of PHP. You can do that or replace the older instructions with the newer ones (`sqlsrv`).

Most Hosting services let you choose the desired PHP version.