# Trying to connect to MS SQL server but it shows an error

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

```
$username = "*******";
$password = "*******";
$hostname = "180.179.67.205";
$dbname = "**********";

//connection to the database
$dbcon = mssql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)or die("Unable to connect to MSSQL");

//select the database
mssql_select_db($dbname, $dbcon);
```

> Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql\_connect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986804/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect)

Comment: @sanjog, have you enabled MSSQL Module !

Comment: @Venkatraman Please explain how can i enable MSSQL Module

Comment: is your server window / linux ?

Comment: i have enable MSSQL Module, still this error is occurred

Comment: hope you restarted the web server apache !

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set up a user with "SQL SERVER authentication" who has rights to connect.

and also check

PHPINFO: mssql
MSSQL Support enabled

Comment: Dear Sir, Please Explain

Comment: please check phpinfo by calling phpinfo() in any php file and check mssql is enabled or not. if not please enabled it. for more info please see this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php)

Comment: cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze"

Comment: please Check and tell me, i'm unable to understand

Answer (score 0):

enable mssql in php.ini

;extension=php_mssql.dll

to

extension=php_mssql.dll

Comment: Dear Sir, Please Explain

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$username = "*******";

$password = "*******";

$hostname = "180.179.67.205";

$dbname = "**********";

//connection to the database

$dbcon = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select the database

mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbcon);

// Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

i changed mssql to mysql because it's not supported in new version

**OR**

I suggest that you comment out the ;php_mssql.dll in the php.ini file and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Dear Sir, Please Explain

Comment: you need to either comment out ;php_mssql.dll from php.ini file like this php_mssql.dll