# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() or sqlsrv_connect() in xampp

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I did all the changes given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986804/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect) but I still not connect SQL server on my php 5.6 version.

I tried with `mssql_connect()` and `sqlsrv_connect()` both.

I changed

`; On windows: extension_dir = "ext"`

to:

`; On windows: extension_dir = "D:\xampp\php\ext"`

I have installed `.dll`s too. But result is still:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

or

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

can anyone help me??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mssql_connect() is no longer supported by PHP since PHP 7.0 and was depreciated in 5.3.

Create a phpinfo.php file:

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

Open the page, and on the first page that's opened, third from the bottom, check if the registered streams contains 'sqlsrv':

```
Registered PHP Streams  php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, phar, sqlsrv
```

If it doesn't then you have to enable the module.
Try uncomment this code that you changed:
From:

```
; On windows: extension_dir = "D:\xampp\php\ext" "
```

To:

```
On windows: extension_dir = "D:\xampp\php\ext"
```

And let us know the outcome.

Comment: Thanks Tommy for your great reply.
It is working fine now.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay, great! Glad I could help. Mark as correct answer? For anyone else who visits this thread.

Comment: After uncommenting that also i got the same error in my php 7.0.9