# cant connect to mssql server or sqlsrv not showing up on phpinfo

Tags: php, sql-server, php-mssql

I have problem to connect to SQL server. I did all the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543053/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect-or-sqlsrv-connect-in-x) and I already changed the `php.ini` configuration file:

```
;On windows: 
extension_dir = "D:\xampp\php\ext"
```

But I still can't connect, my PHP Version is 7.2.11. I tried with `mssql_connect()` and `sqlsrv_connect()`:

This is my attempt:

```
<?php
$servername = "1111";
$username = "user";
$password = "123";
$dbname = "DEV";

$connection = mssql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mssql_get_last_message());} 
$db_selected = mssql_select_db($dbname, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mssql_get_last_message());
} else{

echo "success";}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSSQL extension for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php) (`mssql_` functions) and [PHP Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) (`sqlsrv_` functions) are two different extensions for PHP.

MSSQL extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later, so you need to install PHP Driver for SQL Server. You need to download appropriate version of this driver. For PHP 7.2 - version 5.2 or 5.3 (32-bit or 64-bit also depends on PHP version).
Also download and install an appropriate ODBC driver.

Check the configuration with `<?php phpinfo();?>`. There should be a section with name `pdo_sqlsrv` (if you use PDO) and/or `sqlsrv` (without PDO).

Example:

```
<?php
$server   = '1111';
$database = 'DEV';
$uid      = 'user';
$pwd      = '123';

# SQL Server authentication
#$cinfo = array(
#    "Database" => $database,
#    "UID" => $uid,
#    "PWD" => $pwd
#);

# Windows authentication
$cinfo = array(
    "Database" => $database
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
} else {
    echo "success";
}

sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: oh nice it works, thanks for answering. but i got error, failed login. is it need a permission from administrator?

Comment: @Tri Try with Windows authentication. See updated answer. And post erros, if any. Thanks.