# Cannot connect to mssql server with php

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I want to connect to my mssql server through PHP but it says that there drivers cannot be found.
This is my php-code:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mssql:host=SQL-Server;dbname=Test', 'User', 'Password')
```

already added this line to php.ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_nts.dll
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: are you using windows or linux server?

Comment: I am using a windows server

Comment: https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php check this

Comment: You need to have a module called pdo_mysql. Looking for following in phpinfo(), or restart your server and check

Comment: Do you have a link where I can download it, because I don't have it in my folder?

Comment: https://samsami2u.wordpress.com/2008/06/30/how-to-connect-mssql-with-php/

Comment: One error fixed, but the next one occurs: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

Comment: which version You are using for php?

Comment: because mssql_connect() is no longer supported by PHP since PHP 7.0 and was depreciated in 5.3.

Create a phpinfo.php file:

<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>

Comment: I use php version 7.1.3

Comment: it's no longer supported by PHP since 7.0

Comment: what can I use instead of mssql_connect()

Comment: user this sqlsrv_connect() instead of mssql_connect()

Comment: alright thanks i will try

Answer (score -1):

1: Settings related to your php.ini file:

```
a) Search mssql.secure_connection and put it on if it's off
b) remove comment from the dll extention php_mssql.dll
```

2: Settings related to the dll files.

```
download a file name ntwdblib.dll from the internet. 
Note: (if path not known can be found in php.ini for variable extension_dir)
```

3: restart server

```
<?php    
$serverName = "serverName\\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo)
or die(“Couldn’t connect to SQL Server on $myServer”);

// select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
or die(“Couldn’t open database $myDB”);
```

Comment: They are trying to connect to SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Tried this solution but still cannot connect to the database

Comment: let me check and get back to you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/example-application-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543053/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect-or-sqlsrv-connect-in-x

Comment: user this sqlsrv_connect() instead of mssql_connect()