# PHP on Ubuntu loads MSSQL extension from command line but NOT when run through Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I've been searching and trying for quite a while to find an answer, so will finally ask here.

I have a UBUNTU install from Turnkey LINUX, PHP Ver 5.6.23. 
I have compiled and enabled mssql.so as I require to connect to a MSSQL server.

My simple connect PHP script is so:

```
$server = 'rslocal';

$connect = mssql_connect($server, 'sqluser', 'sqlpassword');

if (!$connect) {
    echo 'can not connect';
}
```

**I can run the above PHP script from the command line and it is successful.**  
**I can also run the FreeTDS tsql utility and connect and query the server from the command line**
When I run it from the browser through Apache, it tells me 
**Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() ...**

I have checked that  php --ini (cli)  and phpinfo() (browser)  both report the same ini file in use.

I am not running SELinux so the setbool commands are not relevant here, however the problems stated by others where SELinux WAS the issue are exactly the same as mine, so perhaps this is a place to start.

My feeling is that it is a security policy or something stopping the extension from loading any function that wants to communicate with an outside server, but I am stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you check phpinfo() have module sqlsrv yet?

Comment: phpinfo() does not report any MSSQL support. I think whatever is stopping it from executing in the browser is stopping phpinfo() from showing it as well.

Comment: Now you can't show phpinfo()? This's a bug or you setting it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Can you see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986804/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. I am not using Windows and the connection functions from the CLI using the same php.ini file.

Comment: Yes I know you not using Windows but you can see phpinfo by create .php file and echo phpinfo(); just that bro xD

Answer (score 0):

I found the "answer". On this distro, Ubuntu 14.x, the command

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

doesn't seem to be enough to reload php. The php.ini change, specifically adding extension=mssql.so had not been not applied when run through apache. This raises the question how to "hard" restart Apache so php.ini changes take, but that's a different question. I only noticed that it worked after a reboot.