# Xampp php 5.6 mssql_connect() Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

Tags: php, php-5.6, php-mssql

I am using Xampp with PHP version 5.6. I was trying to connect using `mssql_connect()` function from the `mssql` PHP extension. But it shows me the error:

> mssql_connect() Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   mssql_connect()

Can anybody help me for the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql\_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986804/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect)

Comment: You need to use `sqlsrv_connect()`.

Comment: **Danger**: PHP 5.6 is beyond end of life and is **unsupported**. Upgrade to a current version of PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanations:**

[MSSQL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php) (`mssql_` functions) is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.

> Warning This feature was REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.
>
> Alternatives to this feature include: PDO_SQLSRV PDO_ODBC SQLSRV
>   Unified ODBC API These functions allow you to access MS SQL Server
>   database.
>
> This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or
>   later.

**Solution:**

What you can do is to install [PHP Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). You need to download the appropriate version of this driver. For PHP 5.6 - version 3.2 (32-bit or 64-bit also depends on PHP version). Also download and install an appropriate ODBC driver.

Sample script:

```
<?php
$serverName = "server\instance,port";
$connectionInfo = array(
    "UID" => "username",
    "PWD" => "password",
    "Database" => "database"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Connected.</br>";
}

// Other code here ...

sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```