# php mssql insert into database

Tags: php, html, sql-server

Currently trying to add a record into my database using a html for into php. I've got the posting working from the form into the php I've tested this with a string. However I just can't seem to get my database connection down correctly.

```
$link = mssql_connect("host", "user*", "pw", "db");
 
// insert
...
?>
```

Error_Log

> [05-Jan-2022 10:43:18 America/Boise] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in /home1/jcodecou/public_html/jwebdesign/maintapp/upload.php:9
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in /home1/jcodecou/public_html/jwebdesign/maintapp/upload.php on line 9

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**, it is *wide open* to SQL injection attacks. **Never** inject unsanitised strings into your database,  *always* use parametrised statements.

Comment: "I just can't seem to get my database connection down correctly", by that, you mean connecting PHP to MSSQL? So the INSERT and POST stuff isn't an issue at all (yet), just `mssql_connect`?

Comment: Is the extension installed? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9986908/231316

Comment: *"Call to undefined function mssql_connect()"* suggests that you have not installed the mssql library; or at least not added it to your configuration.

Comment: Correct. mssql_connect is not defined. Thanks! This is simple testing, it's not for a live application at the moment. But thank you for your concern.

Comment: `mssql_connect()` is deprecated as of PHP 5.3 and removed as of PHP 7.  Have a look at the duplicate I linked to.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look into that now.

@Larnu Injection meaning the strings could be injected via the input form? Would this be possible if you've validated the strings for keywords and specials chars...

Comment: It wouldn't be possible if you parametrised your statements. *Parametrise* your statements.

Comment: @JayW Consider all user input a potential weapon, and have the mindset that you can't possibly expect to validate all the current and future possible ways those weapons could be exploited. Take the possibility away by protecting yourself. See [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-1/) and [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-2/). You're not doing anyone any favors - especially your future self - by assuming you can validate / sanitize perfectly.

Comment: Trying to validate or sanitize makes me think of choosing to put my money in the bank or hide it under a mattress. The bank is insured and I leave the security to them. Under the mattress I need to invest in door locks then window locks then an alarm system and then I need to put a grate in my chimney and then also a lock on my door so the cleaner or my own kids can't steal it and then dye packs in the money because I have to let the cleaner into the bedroom eventually... this sequence is what checking for keywords and special characters makes me imagine.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I'm aware of such attacks and I will learn how to BEST prevent them due to this advice I'll read up on it. This at the moment is just testing a way to do something and isn't going to hurt anything (the database is completely empty)

Comment: The point is to _never_ code this way because (a) those habits stick and bleed into other code (b) you probably won't ever fix this even when it does get promoted to something real and (c) posting it here potentially teaches and reinforces to others that this is ok when it's not.

Comment: I completely understand what you're saying. However right now I'm trying to get the code connected to a database. I'm not passing any information from anything. Once I figure that, I read up on this.

Comment: And, if you didn't expose that you're were making such a fundamental, and fatal, error the comments would not be flooded with people telling you that you have made a fundamental and fatal error. (And, of course, if you'd parametrised in the first place, you also wouldn't have suffered the mass of comments.)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new here as you can see. I'm now leaving I've never been abused so much online in my life - I'm sure you're been helpful but there's most certainly a way to do it which was not that way.

Comment: With respect, if being told that you have major security problems in your code, and what do is instead is "abuse" then you are going to struggle with any constructive help. SQL injection is prolific, fatal, and easily avoidable flaw. There's a reason people jump on about that it's an issue in code, because the vulnerability should have died out like the dinosaurs many years ago. There is a wealth of education out there about the problem, and companies that don't bother to address it are named, shamed, and heavily fined when they are breached; it's just not acceptable to ever use injection now.

Comment: Constructive may well be intended but even now more patronising. Thank you for your inputs I'm going to read on those now. My apologies if any offence was made, but it was most certainly taken. I wish you the best.