# Can't connect to database "Fatal error: Call to undefind function mysqli_connect()"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been scouring this site for 5 hours now trying to get this sorted, I rarely ask for help but this is one of the weirdest and most annoying things I've encountered.

First of all I'd like to say that this DID work fine, I have limited examples of what the cause is but I'll list them anyway.

Here's the full error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefind function mysqli_connect() in C:\wamp\www\game\connect.php on line 3

And here's the code

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","game");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$select_db = mysqli_select_db($con, 'game');
if (!$select_db){
die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Weird thing is, it was working completely fine and just suddenly stopped, this has happened more than once.

Here's what I've tried:

Checking the extensions are enabled -
Rebooting various times -
Setting the correct php path -
Using many example codes that "work" -

I also had some code that inputted data straight from phpdesigner into the database, which successfully worked, but that no longer works and I've made literally 0 changes.

The last time it stopped working, I filled out a registration form on my site as a test (that doesn't work either) and it suddenly went off. When filling in the form I click register and nothing happens besides a refresh.

Bit extra: In my httpd file the pfp and pfpinidir are as follows

php5_module"c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php5apache2_4.dll"

## PHPIniDir "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini"

Comment: Can you tell us more about your server? Is this something local, like XAMPP or EasyPHP? What version of PHP?

Comment: Also, if it is an EasyPHP / XAMPP like, do you have anything in the log files ?

Comment: You will need to check if mysqli extension is enabled

Comment: Server is locally hosted using wamp. MySQL version is 5.6.16. php is 5.5.12 and Apache is 2.4.9. The extensions are enabled, mysql doesn't work as well as mysqli :(

Comment: You could create a dummy php file calling phpinfo(); and ensure that the .ini is correctly loaded (under the "Loaded configuration" part) and that the mysqli extension is really loaded and enabled.

Comment: Makes sense that the mysqli extension wouldn't be loaded or may be having troubles. How do I check if it loaded properly? it's definitely enabled

Comment: Here's a pic of my extensions list, http://imgur.com/FpuS1Ox, look at the top one, when I click that I get this error, http://imgur.com/XLkqm27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to connect to DB twice, plus you're mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_error()`, they do not mix together.

The 4th parameter is the DB name which is what you've done in the first example.

Use either:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","game");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

or omit `,"game"` from `mysqli_connect()` - while `mysqli_error()` requires DB connection parameter.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$select_db = mysqli_select_db($con, 'game');
if (!$select_db){
die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
```

Comment: I think it is connecting anyway, even though it is telling me that it is not. As when I browse to localhost/game/connect.php I get a "success" message which I've inputted at the end of the code, if it wasn't connecting then I wouldn't get that success message, right?

Comment: @RyanMcKenna I tend to think so. Yet, and as mentioned in my answer, you were mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_error()` - did you try my code? Not both together at once though.

Comment: Great, I'll try to continue working on my project, for a hobby it sure is frustrating! EDIT - yes I tried your code, but mine seemed to be working anyway, but I will use yours as it is generally better

Comment: @RyanMcKenna If you were to post your entire INSERT code in your question, I could have a look at it, maybe there's something in there that is causing the problem(s).

Comment: I'll add it now, also my registration doesn't seem to be working so that's kinda disproving the fact that I can connect, here's my code http://codeviewer.org/view/code:442b

Comment: @RyanMcKenna *Hm...* that should be working. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'error_reporting' (T_STRING)  lol :P

Comment: @RyanMcKenna That is very very bizarre. You did copy it correctly right? Try just a quick "hello world" example using `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); echo "Hello world"; ?>` see what that gives.

Comment: Works, when I remove the echo I get no errors messages, so I assume I am actually connecting to my database? - registration still doesn't work and you said it looks correct? I've tried other codes and they don't work either. Can't tell if I'm connecting or not!

Comment: @RyanMcKenna You mean it's not echoing "Hello world" on screen? If it isn't, then PHP isn't properly configured, or you may need to do a new install. I've never seen that error message before. Google yielded about 6 results for that error message.

Comment: It DID echo Hello World, but I removed the echo code

Comment: @RyanMcKenna Then follow the same convention in your DB code `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); // rest of DB codes ?>`

Comment: I already did it with my DB codes lol unless you're talking about something else? put it above the two code samples I gave you and neither give error messages

Comment: @RyanMcKenna See this answer on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/a/5179578/ there might be something in there you may not have done. Plus, MySQL is in fact installed and running, correct? See the other answers in that page also. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18577094/ also - Enable 2 extensions in your php.ini

extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll

Comment: What file should these 3 be directing to?Located in the php.ini file,  extension_dir, user_dir and doc_root. The last two are currently empty EDIT MySQL looks to be running happily via the wamp UI and those extensions are enabled

Comment: @RyanMcKenna That I can't be certain, I've never installed PHP/webserver before. I Google'd what I could and that's what I found; thought it would point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ah okay, well the error message doesn't go away (it's only when I click "Run" from phpdesigner 8 lol) but I think it's connecting

Comment: @RyanMcKenna I'm sure if you upload it on a hosted site, it will work. There's probably some silly little setting somewhere that needs to be changed.

Comment: Omg I hate myself. Had an entry to add the "name" but I had the table set to "username", changed it and it's now working!

Answer (score 2):

Your mysqli extension might not be enabled. so u need to enable that.

You have two PHP binaries on your machine. One is connected to the Apache, and is the one u use when you surf to a web page. 
The phpinfo() shows you which php.ini file is used by the web php binary. u need to edit this file and in it activate the mysqli extension

Comment: The extension is enabled, same for normal mysql (which doesn't work either)

Comment: You able to connect with phpmyadmin? is your mysql server is running?